# Spring data Mongodb Store and query GIS Circle and Polygon

Tags: spring, mongodb, gis, polygon, geometry

I've a simple use-case to solve using MongoDB with Spring-data connectors.

- Store a polygon or circle (simple Point with radius)
- Check if give point is inside polygon/circle

Now, I've done like this:

- Store give Polygon as a geoJSON into a document
- Apply 2dSphere index
- Polygon stored as a Polygon geoJSON type
- Circle stored a single point and radius as separate parameter
- Polygons I'm able to query using $geoIntersects
- Circle I'm able to query using $geoNear with aggregation

Problem:

- What is right way to store and index Circle(Point and radius) and Polygon (multiple points)?
- How to do a single query to check if given point reside in Polygon / Circle?

Comment: can you explain, currently how you are inserting the polygon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently Spring Data does not support this kind of  query ($geoIntersects) using   MongoRepository interface, but this works for me:
Let's suppose that we have the following document

```
@Document
public class AreaTown {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @GeoSpatialIndexed(type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
    private GeoJsonPolygon  area;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public GeoJsonPolygon getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(GeoJsonPolygon area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AreaTown [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", area=" + area + "]";
    }

}
```

Applying a custom Query, I was able to found if a point is inside of a polygon

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MongoGeoJsonApplication   implements CommandLineRunner{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MongoGeoJsonApplication.class, args);
    }



    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {  

        Point inside  = new Point(-97.406285,18.481136);
        Query query = new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("area").intersects(new GeoJsonPoint(inside)));
        List<AreaTown> list = mongoTemplate.find(query, AreaTown.class);
        System.out.println(list);



    }
}
```